# Standard console output without nextline

Tags: c++, console, newline

I would like to write 80 (standard conole width) characters in one line without the cursor go to next line. It is only problem when I want to print 80 characters in the **last** line of console. It cases scrolling that I dont want.

Take a look:

[image]

I dont want the newline. any way to do this? :/
Im on Windows, DEV-C++, using WinApi for colors and moving the cursor (the window resize too).

Thanx for any answers.

Comment: post a code snippet of what you did

Comment: @Dirk: how would that help? His problem is clearly stated, there is little need for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using standard output functions use the Windows Console API to set the cursor position and draw characters. Specifically, take a look at `WriteConsoleOutput`.

[MSDN Console API Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why you are on a  new line is because the console is not big enought to support the eighty stars.

So it pushed the cursor to the next line.

Comment: I know it :) But how can I prevent cursor moving after putting char?

Answer (score 0):

through one or two "\b" at the end it moves the cursor back.

Comment: doesnt help. I think that it doesnt move it up :/

Comment: well there isn't any up or down in console it's just a \n\r that moves the cursor to the next line or just it's really really full.

Answer (score 0):

For the system-critical console window, the cursor should always stay visible, and the only way for it to do so after you've reached the max number of chars in a line, is to pop up on the next visible line (without actually making any new lines).

Answer (score 0):

filter the output either in the originating program or with another program through a pipe.  When you have outputted too many characters on a single line, do whatever you like (i.e., drop characters, overwrite, etc....).